# Range.Find not finding existing value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that loops through every worksheet in a workbook and records the "bill area" each worksheet is about and some other information in each workbook. My program works for the first worksheet but doesn't work for the second worksheet. The same standardized text that I am searching for is there, yet Range.Find is not working. Here is the code:

```
Sub DenialsReport()

Dim heatWB, denialWB As Workbook
Dim heatWS, denialWS As Worksheet
Dim folderName, fileName, extName, wbName, billArea, postPeriod As String
Dim a, b, lastRow, countCol, volumeCol, startRow, billAreaRow, billAreaColumn, grandRow As Long
Dim postPeriodRange, billAreaRange, grandRange As Range

Set heatWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set heatWS = heatWB.Sheets("Denials")

postPeriod = InputBox("Please enter the current post period in this form: yyyymm")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

folderName = heatWB.Sheets("Support->").Cells(19, 3).Value
fileName = heatWB.Sheets("Support->").Cells(20, 3).Value
extName = heatWB.Sheets("Support->").Cells(21, 3).Value
wbName = folderName + "\" + fileName + "." + extName

Set denialWB = Workbooks.Open(wbName)

b = 0

For Each denialWS In Worksheets

    denialWS.Cells.UnMerge

Next denialWS

For Each denialWS In Worksheets

    b = b + 1
    denialWB.Sheets(b).Cells.UnMerge
    lastRow = heatWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' find the bill area
    Set billAreaRange = denialWB.Sheets(b).Range("A1:G10").Find(What:="For Bill Area: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    billAreaRow = billAreaRange.Row
    billAreaColumn = billAreaRange.Column

    ' get the bill area
    billArea = denialWB.Sheets(b).Cells(billAreaRow, billAreaColumn).Value
    billArea = Replace(billArea, "For Bill Area: ", "")
    billArea = Left(billArea, InStr(billArea, "(") - 1)
    billArea = Trim(billArea)

    ' locate the count and amount columns along with the start and end of the rejection categories
    Set postPeriodRange = d enialWB.Sheets(denialWS.Index).Range("A1:AZ15").Find(What:=postPeriod, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    countCol = postPeriodRange.Column
    amountCol = countCol + 1
    startRow = postPeriodRange.Row + 2
    Set grandRange = denialWB.Sheets(denialWS.Index).Range("A:A").Find(What:="Grand Total",    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    grandRow = grandRange.Row

    ' copy the information over to heatWS
    For a = startRow To grandRow - 1
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = billArea
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = postPeriod
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = denialWS.Cells(a, 1).Value
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 4).Value = denialWS.Cells(a, countCol).Value
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 5).Value = denialWS.Cells(a, amountCol).Value
        heatWS.Cells(lastRow, 6).Value = denialWS.Cells(a, amountCol).Value /    denialWS.Cells(grandRow, amountCol).Value
        lastRow = heatWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next a

Next denialWS

denialWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

heatWS.Range("A:F").AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem occurs on this line:

```
Set billAreaRange = denialWB.Sheets(b).Range("A1:G10").Find(What:="For Bill Area: ", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

I have also tried to hardcode the program like this (value lies in cell C7):

```
billArea = denialWB.Sheets(b).Cells(7,3).Value
```

I believe this means that VBA isn't recognizing that there is a value in the cell. However, I am able to physically enter the cell and make edits. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Likely not your issue, but use the `denialWS` reference. `denialWS.Range("A1:G10").Find`.  `For Each` looping over the worksheets and then manually trying to keep the index in sync is silly. It's also error prone, because an enumerated collection isn't required to return them in index order.

Comment: I had previously used denialWS.Range("A1:G10").Find but when that didn't work I manually kept track of the index. It was my way of diagnosing where the error occurred. Neither works.

Comment: Please, remove all the excessive code which doesn't have any meaning to question...

Answer (score 1):

You've got more than a few things in your code that can easily be working against you. So in addition to a suggestion for answering your question, here are some common issues that I see that can cause problems.

A single, common declaration line such as

```
Dim folderName, fileName, extName, wbName, billArea, postPeriod As String
```

does **NOT** assign the type `String` to all of those variables. In this case, only the last declaration `postPeriod As String` declares that variable of type `String`. All of the other variables default to the type `Variant`. The standard practice is to use a single line declaration for each variable, each with a specific type. Additionally, your code can appear much cleaner to declare the variable/type immediately before using it for the first time. In this way, you don't have to scroll way back up to the top to figure out what the type is. So:

```
Dim folderName As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim extName As String
...
```

Next, [read this explanation](https://analystcave.com/vba-tip-day-activeworkbook-vs-thisworkbook/) of the difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`. Almost always, it's the latter form you want. So you should

```
Dim heatWB As Workbook
Set heatWB = ThisWorkbook
```

You have two loops which use

```
For Each denialWS In Worksheets
    ...
Next denialWS
```

My assumption in reading this line is that you are looping through worksheets in the ActiveWorkbook. But the variable `denialWS` implies that you really want to be looping through the worksheets of the `denialWB`. If that's the case, then use

```
For Each denialWS In denialWB.Worksheets
    ...
Next denialWS
```

Further, in the next loop, you're getting to each worksheet in the workbook, BUT you're confusing things by setting the `b` variable (why?) and using that to index through the worksheets as well. So it's very unclear which sheet you're operating on. (Why not use `denialWS` instead?)

At last to get to your question involving `Find`. It can easily be the case if you clean up the problems mentioned here, your `Find` issue will be solved. But you should also account for the case where it fails. So use something like

```
Set billAreaRange = denialWS.Range("A1:G10").Find(What:="For Bill Area: ", _
                                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                  MatchCase:=False)
If not billAreaRange Is Nothing Then
    billAreaRow = billAreaRange.Row
    billAreaColumn = billAreaRange.Column
    ... <the rest of your logic here>
Else
    <raise an error or display a MsgBox here>
    Exit For
End If
```

Fixing all these things should also give you a fix for the hard-coded test you tried as well.